# Can I use speech framework to recognise some special phrases?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

Can I use speech framework to recognize some special phrases?

I want to give a list of special phrases like brand's names to be recognized.

Is it possible to achieve? How can I do that?

Comment: have you read SiriKit docs ?

Comment: sirikit only support customised words for its intents. please read the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Speech Recognition API does not support this. However if you only need to recognise some specific phrases you could use third party solutions like http://www.politepix.com/openears/. And it also works offline.